# Error: Invalid or unknown request type (not a Dialogflow v1 or v2 webhook request)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

when i run `firebase serve --only functions`

this is my code:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function findWidget(agent) {
  agent.add(`You are now being handled by the productivity intent`);
  const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
  return request.get(url)
      .then(jsonBody => {
          var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
          agent.add(body.data[0].first_name)
          return Promise.resolve(agent);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error('Problem making network call', err);
          agent.add('Unable to get result');
          return Promise.resolve(agent);
      });
  };

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', findWidget);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

pls help me fix this problem, i don't know what wrong with that.

Update:error image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YDP2.png
        screenshot browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPV9w.png

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate what you are doing to trigger the webhook? You may want to also include what Dialogflow Intents you have in the console or other screen shots to illustrate how you are testing this.

Comment: hi @Prisoner i updated my question, pls help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although we say that the Dialogflow [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) code is meant to run as a webhook, it does not necessarily mean that you will be able to access it in a web browser.

In this case, a Dialogflow webhook fulfillment needs to

- Listen at a publicly available HTTPS address
- Accept an HTTP POST command...
- ... that can handle a JSON body in the [Dialogflow webhook request format](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#request_format)...
- ... and return a JSON body in the [Dialogflow webhook response format](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#response_format).

The [Dialogflow fulfillment library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-nodejs-lib) is designed to accept the formatted request and help you create a formatted response.

However, in your case, you accessed it using a web browser. Which likely used a HTTP GET command, and did not send a JSON body. The error message is telling you that the request didn't look like it came from Dialogflow, so it can't handle it.